# How to connect to a MySQL Data Source in Visual Studio 2010 express on x64 bit/x32 bit machine

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I have installed the MySQL NET Connector 6.0 and am currently unable to get Visual Studio 2010 to recognize that the connector is installed. Is there a trick to do this with the beta connector?
The following are the steps I followed to try to connect Visual Studio 2010 with MySQL,

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=12345;database=test;";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Unfortunately, I still don’t get the required Data Sources,

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, or if I am missing any packages and how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Connection string correct that you provided???First may be try to connect to server using VS2010 and test the connection

Answer (score 0):

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate) installed on my WINDOWS 7(32).

Here's what worked for me hope it'll help you too:

C# code:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DELL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
 myConnection.Open();
```

Since SQL SERVER was preinstalled in the VS I did not go for connector software.

Find the SQLEXPRESS(if it's there) or try using compact preinstalled version 
Change the machine name in the data source and database name as well.